# PHP - Count downloads

Tags: php

I'ld like to count file downloads with PHP. The downloads number should be stored in a .TXT file.

How that can be done?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146/how-do-i-track-file-downloads-with-apache-php - I particularly like grep'ing the access.log

Comment: I've edited the code to include an initial variable initialization that was previously rendered invisible by the code formatter. Also, I changed the $count++ to ++$count, in order to increment **before** writing and also treated the initial case when no file yet exists.

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a file named, say, `download.php`, with the following content:

```
<?php
 $Down=$_GET['Down'];
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?php echo $Down; ?>">
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php

  $filePath = $Down.".txt";

  // If file exists, read current count from it, otherwise, initialize it to 0
  $count = file_exists($filePath) ? file_get_contents($filePath) : 0;

  // Increment the count and overwrite the file, writing the new value
  file_put_contents($filePath, ++$count);

  // Display current download count
  echo "Downloads:" . $count;
 ?> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Put a link to it in another page, with the file to be downloaded as a parameter:

`download.php?Down=download.zip`

Answer reference [Dreamincode answer to a similar question](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/11803-how-do-i-count-downloads-from-my-website/)

Comment: This looks great but the counter isn't working. Anything I missed? The .txt file starts with "0" counts and a CHMOD 777.

Comment: @Uli What should exactly do after creating download.php file?

Comment: Be careful, if you have your website in the internet! Everbody could download everthing from your server with this solution.

Comment: @knobli That is not true - this implementation only puts redirect between link to the file and actual file, AFAIK no new security risks are introduced.

Comment: what about if the file download get's interrupted ? It will also count ad download ?

Comment: @FanaticD The file that gets downloaded is determined by the $get which in turn, is determined by the URL. An attacker could just modify the URL to get whatever file whose filename they could guess or see.  Genesis's solution shown below is more secure.

Comment: @Michael In my original comment, I was wrong. There are additional issues introduced. But you are still not quite correct about where they are. There is a reflected XSS (rendering unsanitized input from URL directly into the page) and an unvalidated redirect. You and @knobli are misunderstanding how `meta refresh` works though. An attacker can modify the URL to whatever file they want, but it will not force the download of that file. It will only redirect the user to that file (if the file is let's say .php, **it will not be downloaded**, but executed).

Comment: @Michael If you'd like to discuss this more, we can do so in [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) (PHP room).

Answer (score 12):

```
$current_count = file_get_contents('count');
$f = fopen('count', 'w+');
fwrite($f, $current_count + 1);
fclose($f);

header("Location: file.zip");
```

Comment: what about if the file download get's interrupted ? It will also count ad download ?

Comment: @daslicht Yes, it will count as a download. What the code does is 1) increases a counter 2) redirects a user to the file to be downloaded. If a user chooses not to press 'save' or 'download' after prompted, it will still be counted in as if they would download it.