# Is PHP and SQL enough to count page views and number of downloads?

Tags: php, mysql, counter, pageviews

Can anyone help with this, if PHP and MySQL enough to count page views/number of downloads precisely? I need to count how many times a wallpaper is being downloaded.

If yes, how can we do that? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I need to count how many times a wallpaper is being downloaded.

Comment: Please post your code for how your wallpaper is being served out. If it is just a right-click / save as situation, then you cannot track *that*. So you will need to track page views. It's not terribly accurate, but is "close enough for horse shoes and hand grenades..."

Comment: what's "enough"? Yes, php and mysql can both do simple "x = x + 1" type math.

Comment: if you dont want to code it yourself there is always google analytics

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of online tutorials for creating page hit counters. There are several on phpAcademy.org alone.

You might find this one to be most helpful:

https://phpacademy.org/course/unique-hit-counter

---

And here is a tutorial video for setting up Google Analytics on your site:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUTNLzzde60

As well as [an article for Beginners](http://searchengineland.com/google-analytics-installation-for-novices-and-beginners-133384)

Answer (score 0):

mysql is not even needed to solve that problem.

here it is solved by writing a file with the download count

[PHP - Count downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213940/php-count-downloads)