# Collecting statistics for my android app

Tags: android

I know many analytics tools are available online to track app's performance. But I am referring to personalised statistics.

I have an android app which lets users download question papers and various other files in pdf format. I would like to know total number of files downloaded to date. What I think:

1. Host a file on my server with text "0"
2. Create 2 AsyncTasks and call one to get the value in file.
3. Store it in a variable as integer and increment it.
4. Call 2nd asynctask and overwrite existing file's values by now stored variable.

I don't know if any easier way exists like Firebase? If yes, please give some details.

Comment: I would track these kind of stats on the server...

Comment: don't do it in android.. collect data on server.. sample script - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213940/php-count-downloads

Comment: @AmodGokhale and then call this file using Asynctask?

Comment: it depends upon your Android Code.. your question is specific to download count, for that call need not be async

Comment: AsyncTasks are for moving the network request into the background so that won't block the UI thread. What you really need is HttpURLConnection in your AsyncTask's doInBackground() function. Alternatively you could use other network management libraries but let's stick to the basics :).